# Two ADO Models , How to conditinally select one of them

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, ado

I have two Databases. One of these is for development, and the other for production.

My main target is to have two databases and conditionally select one of them by setting a value in the application settings.
Here is the code to explain more of what I need to achieve:

```
private  DbContext DB;
public Order(Sql sql, Employee emp)
{
    DB = Settings.Default.Develop ? this.DB = new developEntities() : this.DB = new Entities();
}
```

However this code works, but when selecting a specific table it gives me an error that it's undefined.
How I can manage the program between two development environments?

Comment: Isn't this just a connection string you're switching? You can pass one to a dbcontext.

Answer (score 0):

I found this one  :-

```
public Entities(string con)
    : base(con)
{
}

   Entities DB = new Entities(Settings.Default.Develop ? "name=developEntities" : "name=Entities");
```